How to install python 3.x with debug library (i.e. python3xx_d.lib) in anaconda in windows?
I see this pull request seem to be related to my problem and it was merged.
I think maybe python 3.11 on anaconda include the debug library. So, I install it by the following command:
conda install conda-forge::python=3.11

However, I can only find python3.lib and python311.lib, but not python3_d.lib or python311_d.lib. Is it possible to install python 3.x with debug library in anaconda?
